# Changes of ScriptableObject don't appear on git client's Local Changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, git-fork, odin-inspector

Here I have two ScriptableObjects.

One in "TestScriptableObject.cs"

```
using System;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TestScriptableObject", menuName = "ScriptableObject/TestScriptableObject")]
public class TestScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string currentTime;
        
    [Button]
    public void Change()
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
    }
}
```

The other one in TestScriptableObject2.cs"

```
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using UnityEngine;

namespace JimmyTest
{
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TestScriptableObject2", menuName = "ScriptableObject/TestScriptableObject2")]
    public class TestScriptableObject2 : ScriptableObject
    {
        public string currentTime;
        public TestScriptableObject TestScriptableObject;
        
        [Button]
        private void Change()
        {
            TestScriptableObject.Change();
        }
    }
}
```

When I press a button in TestScriptableObject.asset, it changes the value of 'currentTime' and clearly git client knows the change. but When I press a button in TestScriptableObject2.asset, it changes the value but the git client doesn't show me the change.
I'm using git fork.

Anyone got this kind of issues before?

I want the git client to show me the changes.

Comment: Try pressing **Ctrl + S** , sometimes unity doesn't save some assets instantly (especially for ScriptableObject assets

Comment: I've already tried "Save Project" but It didn't work.

Comment: You should maybe call [`EditorUtility.SetDirty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) on it after modifying the value.

Comment: @MaxPlay It solved the issue thanks! btw still I wonder why it doesn't show up on changes...